# Sinon Spy / Stub for Function inside Function (Private Function)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I'm new `Sinon`. i'm unable to spy the private `ajax` function

#### Actual code in `library.js`

```
function ajax () {
    console.log("I'm a");
}

function getJSON() {
    ajax();
    console.log("I'm b");
}

exports.getJSON = getJSON;
```

#### Actual Test Code

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var lib = require('./library');

describe('Tutor Test', function () {
    it('getJSON Calling ajax', function (done) {
        var ajax = sinon.spy(lib, 'ajax');
        lib.getJSON();

        ajax.restore();
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(ajax);
        done();
    });
});
```

> Note: I already tried with below object example. it works like charm.

#### Working Code in `library.js`

```
var jquery = {
    ajax: function () {
        console.log("I'm a");
    },

    getJSON: function () {
        this.ajax();
        console.log("I'm b");
    }
};

exports.jquery = jquery;
```

#### Working Test Cases.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var $ = require('./library').jquery;

describe('Tutor Test', function () {
    it('getJSON Calling ajax', function (done) {
        var ajax = sinon.spy($, 'ajax');
        $.getJSON();

        ajax.restore();
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(ajax);
        done();
    });
});
```

I'm getting error like below during `mocha test`

```
1) Tutor Test getJSON Calling ajax:
     TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property ajax as function
      at Object.wrapMethod (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/util/core.js:113:29)
      at Object.spy (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js:41:26)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:41:26)
```

Comment: It's not working in the first case because there's no function `ajax` exported in your `library.js`

Comment: `yes i know. that is the question without exporting `ajax` which is not required for application but needed for test case.`

Comment: Sinon will not work in this case as you expect it

Comment: so `sinon` does not work for functional code

Comment: @Boss first in your example, that's **not functional code**, that's procedural code, and it will not work because ajax function is private to the `library.js` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### As far as i know, Spying private Variables / Function is not possible in `Sinon`. So avoid using `Sinon` for those use cases.

> Note: Your (`ajax`) function does not have param and return value and not bind to the exported object is real challenge for `sinon`

In such case, If you wanted to make sure whether `ajax` function is triggered or not. You can use `rewire`.

Below is the working code.

```
var rewire = require('rewire');
var lib = rewire('./library');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Tutor Test', function () {
    it('getJSON Calling ajax', function (done) {
        lib.__set__('isAjaxCalled', false);
        lib.__set__('ajax', function () {
            lib.__set__('isAjaxCalled', true);
        });

        lib.getJSON();
        assert.equal(lib.__get__('isAjaxCalled'), true);
        done();
    });
});
```

> #### No Change your Actual code, library.js

Comment: Is there still no workaround for this particular problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Call your method from the exported public API.

```
var jquery = {
    ajax: function () {
        console.log("I'm a");
    },

    getJSON: function () {
        //this.ajax();
        jquery.ajax(); // <---
        console.log("I'm b");
    }
};
```

Another approach is to call console.log with a hint, and then spy on the log.

```js
ajax: function () {
  console.log("I'm a");
},
```

```js
var ajax = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
$.getJSON();
sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly("I'm a")
```